# AVPlayer play with update label cause an issue

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an issue with `AVPlayer` play and same time updates label.

I have timer that updates label with progress of player, but that stuck my video at same position...check below image..After button click timer starts and cause an issue..

[image]

**Code:**

```
func playVideo() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("videoname", ofType:"mp4")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    
    moviePlayer = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
    
    //  Play the video
    moviePlayer!.play()
}

@IBAction func progresss(sender: UIButton) {
    self.meterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1,
        target:self,
        selector:"updateAudioMeter:",
        userInfo:nil,
        repeats:true)
}

func updateAudioMeter(timer:NSTimer) {
    lbltime.text = "\(CMTimeGetSeconds(moviePlayer!.currentItem.currentTime()))"
}
```

**Sample project link**

> [Source code](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04212485841499293439)
>
> Note:please add video in bundle if you are use sample project.I just delete video because of file size

**Question**

- How to avoid this? and why this happens because when I used MPMovieController it works great.

Comment: @ElCaptain use `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` callback method of `AVPlayer` instead `NSTimer` directly.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara  no not working...it gives same effect and after that crash

Comment: @ElCaptain i have posted `Objective-C` sample you can write same code for `swift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample code the problem is below function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: moviePlayer)
    layer.frame = self.viewPlayer.frame
    self.viewPlayer.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

This will resize your layer view every time when your label update so just remove and add that code into `playVideo` method and your method will be:

```
func playVideo() {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "MOV")
    let url  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    moviePlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    moviePlayer!.allowsExternalPlayback = false

    var introPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: moviePlayer)
    viewPlayer.layer.addSublayer(introPlayerLayer)
    introPlayerLayer.frame = viewPlayer.bounds
    moviePlayer!.play()
}
```

And call this method in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` method and your complete code will be:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer : AVPlayer?
    var meterTimer : NSTimer!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewPlayer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbltime: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        playVideo()
    }

    func playVideo() {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "MOV")
        let url  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        moviePlayer!.allowsExternalPlayback = false

        var introPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: moviePlayer)
        viewPlayer.layer.addSublayer(introPlayerLayer)
        introPlayerLayer.frame = viewPlayer.bounds
        moviePlayer!.play()
    }

    @IBAction func progresss(sender: UIButton) {

        moviePlayer?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        moviePlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: nil, usingBlock: {
            (CMTime) -> Void in

            self.updateProgressBar()
        })

    }

    func updateProgressBar(){
        var timeNow = Int(self.moviePlayer!.currentTime().value) / Int(self.moviePlayer!.currentTime().timescale)

        var currentMins = timeNow / 60
        var currentSec = timeNow % 60

        var duration: String = "\(currentMins):\(currentSec)"

        self.lbltime.text = duration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code for `Objective-C`, you can convert same in `swift` for your project accordingly.

```
// Implement following code in AVPlayer observer method for `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` state

[avPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(interval, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                       queue:NULL
                                  usingBlock:
 ^(CMTime time)
 {
     // update label value here, it keeps invoking periodically internally.
     CMTime playerDuration = [self playerItemDuration];
 }]; 


// Method to get Player current time 
- (CMTime)playerItemDuration
{
    AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItem = [avPlayer currentItem];
    if (thePlayerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
    {

        return([avPlayerItem duration]);
    }

    return(kCMTimeInvalid);
}
```

if you simply want to update it then invoke `playerItemDuration` to get current time, but make it `asynchronous` process.

Comment: but what you say is ok...but the problem is when I update label then somehow it not works like above it gives same effect...

Comment: try given code and check impact. because its the standard way of doing it.